# Calculating which plane intersects a number of vectors so that the intersection points or all on the circumference of a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a plane in $R^3$ that is defined by:

$$
(E - O)/h \cdot (x - O) + h = 0
$$
$E$ is a point located on the plane. $O$ is the origin and h is the distance between $E$ and $O$. $x$ is a point where $P_n$ (below) intersects this plane.

If I have a set of $N$ unit vectors:
$
\{P_n, n =1,2, \ldots, N\} 
$.

How do I calculate the plane equation so that $E$ is at a point that represents the center point of a circle whose circumference includes all the intersection points of the plane with $P_n$? Namely:

$$
\|P_1 - E\| = \|P_2 - E\| = \ldots = \|P_N-E\|
$$

I need the computationally solve for $E$. Please recommend possible numerical methods I could use and how to implement them.

Comment: In general, there may be no solution. If you have more than 3 vectors that intersect the plane, they may not all fall on the same circle and your problem has no solution.

Comment: I know from the physical system that I'm modeling that a solution does exist